# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Hybrid app build fails when run in Xcode

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

**Bitcode is disabled.**

After selecting Run As-> Xcode Project in MobileFirst Studio, trying to run the project in Xcode yields this error:
[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9DYG.png)

The framework is there and the .h is inside framework/Headers, as you can see in the image.

Using: Xcode7.2, MobileFirst7.1

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: `/Users/apsMac1/Documents/workspace/CICO/apps/cico_hybrid/iphone/native/Classes/cicohybrid.h:6:9: 'IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.h' file not found`

Comment: What is your MobileFirst 7.1 build number?

Comment: Not sure how to check build number for MF

Comment: In the console -> about

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode:
Build Settings (for target)->Search Paths->Framework Search Paths[Double Click]
In the drop-down next to $(PROJECT_DIR), select Recursive. Then try building again. It fixed my issue.